# Radionbuttons checking in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net

It's possible check if one of radio buttons named of 'foo' is selected? For example:

```
<input type="radio" name="foo" id="baa"  value="..."   runat="server" />
<input type="radio" name="foo" id="baa1" value="....." runat="server" />
```

the question is: Is there some `<asp:..` that can test if one(not both, only one can be selected) of above checkbox if selected?

I hope this is clear. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**EDIT**

For you requirement it better to go for  **RadioButtonList** with **RequiredFieldValidator**. Below is example

```
<asp:RadioButtonList 
    ID="RadioButtonList1"
    runat="server"
    RepeatColumns="3">
    <asp:ListItem>abcd</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem>xyz</asp:ListItem>
</asp:RadioButtonList>
<asp:RequiredFieldValidator 
    ID="ReqiredFieldValidator1"
    runat="server"
    ControlToValidate="RadioButtonList1"
    ErrorMessage="select atleast one radiobutton!">*
</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
```

---

You need to group radio button **GroupName="foo"** is group in which two radio button resides , so at a time only one get slected

```
<asp:panel runa="server" id="container">
    <asp:RadioButton id="Radio1" GroupName="foo"
                 Text="Beef" BackColor="Pink" runat="server"/>

            <br />
            <asp:RadioButton id="Radio2" GroupName="foo"
                 Text="Pork" BackColor="Pink" runat="server"/>
</asp:panel>
```

Note even in your html you need to specify groupname for the radio button to select one out of the group of radio button

To check ratio button selected or not just use this linq operation

```
bool isradchecked=container.Controls.OfType<RadioButton>)
                     .Any(r => r.Checked);
```

here container of radiobutton is `Asp:Panel`.

Comment: Thanks! I'II try it. But if I want to show an error message if the user don't select one of radio buttos, how to do this?

Comment: Thank you again. But is there how to do it by using `<asp:..`? something like this `<asp:.... runat="server" 
                ControlToValidate="foo"
                 ErrorMessage="you need to select one radio button" />`?

Comment: @Jack _ i updated my answer i.e edit my answer just use that will resolve you issue without writing any extra code